# SQL Server - Update and select

Tags: sql-server

I have a query which gets a messages from the database. It requires the `OFFSET FETCH` clause for my frontend to paginate the messages.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM messages
WHERE messages.user = @user
ORDER BY messages.date
      OFFSET @page * 5 ROWS
      FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

I now want the query so when it is run it sets `read` column of messages returned by select to be seen.

I have tried changing my select query to a update and then using `output` to get the results. Problem it says I can't use `order by` on a update query let alone pagination with offset and fetch.

I guess what I want to do is (but it's obviously not valid):

```sql
SELECT 
    messages.content,
    messages.from,
    SET messages.read = 1
FROM 
    messages
WHERE 
    messages.user = @user
ORDER BY 
    messages.date
    OFFSET @page * 5 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

How can I implement this?

Comment: You can't update and select in one go. You'll need to do it in two steps which means you'll need to use a stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your table has a primary key, you can use a trick with a common table expression and a merge statement with an output clause.
The problem, as you've noticed, is that you can't update the table inside a `select` statement, and you can't use an `order by` clause in an `update` statement.

What you can do, however, is to create a common table expression that will do the paging for you, and use a `merge` statement on that common table expression to update the `read` column and output the columns you want.
You could do that with an `update` statement, but then you will also have to update the columns you want to output, since the `output` clause of an `update` statement can only be populated with values from the `inserted` pseudo table.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @messages As TABLE
(
    -- Please don't call your primary key column pk, this is just for the demonstration
    pk int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    content varchar(100),
    [from] varchar(10),
    [user] varchar(10),
    [date] datetime,
    [read] bit
)

INSERT INTO @messages(Content, [from], [user], [date], [read]) VALUES
('Test1',  'me', 'you', DATEADD(DAY, -15, getdate()), 0),
('Test2',  'me', 'you', DATEADD(DAY, -14, getdate()), 0),
('Test3',  'me', 'you', DATEADD(DAY, -13, getdate()), 0),
('Test4',  'me', 'you', DATEADD(DAY, -12, getdate()), 0),
('Test5',  'me', 'you', DATEADD(DAY, -11, getdate()), 0),
('Test6',  'me', 'you', DATEADD(DAY, -10, getdate()), 0),
('Test7',  'me', 'you', DATEADD(DAY, -09, getdate()), 0),
('Test8',  'me', 'you', DATEADD(DAY, -08, getdate()), 0),
('Test9',  'me', 'you', DATEADD(DAY, -07, getdate()), 0),
('Test10', 'me', 'you', DATEADD(DAY, -06, getdate()), 0),
('Test11', 'me', 'you', DATEADD(DAY, -05, getdate()), 0),
('Test12', 'me', 'you', DATEADD(DAY, -04, getdate()), 0),
('Test13', 'me', 'you', DATEADD(DAY, -03, getdate()), 0),
('Test14', 'me', 'you', DATEADD(DAY, -02, getdate()), 0),
('Test15', 'me', 'you', DATEADD(DAY, -01, getdate()), 0);
```

Declare the variables you need, (putting in sample values):

```
DECLARE @User varchar(10) = 'you',
        @Page int = 0;
```

The common table expression:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT 
    pk,
    content,
    [from],
    [read]
FROM 
    @messages
WHERE 
    [user] = @user
ORDER BY 
    date
    OFFSET @page * 5 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
)
```

The merge statement:

```
MERGE INTO CTE As Target
USING CTE As Source 
    ON Target.pk = Source.pk
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET [read] = 1
OUTPUT Source.content, Source.[from];
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](https://rextester.com/IVRRD43159)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you, there is no way to do it in one, it may be possible/more elegant with a merge query. Anyway here is an option;

```
--// Get the page, put in temp table \\--
SELECT * INTO #Messages
FROM messages
WHERE messages.user = @user
ORDER BY messages.date
OFFSET @page * 5 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;

--// Set Read Flag \\--
UPDATE M
SET read = 1
FROM messages AS M
INNER JOIN #Messages AS R
ON R.PrimaryKey = M.PrimaryKey 
/*
-- or Composite key based on data
OM   M.content = R.content 
AND  M.from = R.from
AND  M.user = R.User
*/

--// Return the messages \\--
SELECT * FROM #Messages;

--// Tidy up \\--
DROP TABLE #Messages;
```

Hope this helps :)